# Argument 'TabsCtrl1' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

i have this controller and am getting the following error message

*Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TabsCtrl1' is not a function, got undefined http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.11/ng/areq?p0=TabsCtrl1&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined minErr/<@http://localhost:8082/js/lib/angular/angular.js:78:12 assertArg@http://localhost:8082/js/lib/angular/angular.js:1583:11*

```
'use strict';

var tabs = angular.module('opsUI.tabs.controller', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('TabsCtrl1', function ($scope, $rootScope, $route) {
        $scope.showViewTab = true;

if ($route.current === undefined) {
    if ($rootScope.login === undefined) {
        $rootScope.menu = true;
    }
    return;
} else if ($route.current.loadedTemplateUrl == '/login/partials/login.html'){
    $rootScope.menu = false;
    $rootScope.login = true;
} else {
    $rootScope.menu = true;
}


$scope.tabs = [
   { title:'Postal Address', content:'Dynamic content 1' },
   { title:'Dynamic Title 2', content:'Dynamic content 2', disabled: true     }
];
});
```

with this html

```
<div class="app-bar-container">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="border-right: 1px solid #F2F2F2; padding-right: 15px;">
        <button data-ng-controller="TabsCtrl1" class="menu" data-ng-show="menu"><img src="/../images/hamburger.svg"></button>Menu
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="/../images/multiply.png" alt="" style="padding-left: 15px; height: 35px;width: 135px; margin-top:18px;"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

i am getting this error

[image]

anyone who can assist?

Comment: did you included `opsUI.tabs.controller` module inside your `mainAppModule`?

Comment: Just try to change `var tabs`  to `var tabsList`. and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the controller this way. Let me know if it helps

```js
'use strict';

var Controller = function($scope, $rootScope, $route) {
  $scope.showViewTab = true;

  if ($route.current === undefined) {
    if ($rootScope.login === undefined) {
      $rootScope.menu = true;
    }
    return;
  } else if ($route.current.loadedTemplateUrl == '/login/partials/login.html') {
    $rootScope.menu = false;
    $rootScope.login = true;
  } else {
    $rootScope.menu = true;
  }

  $scope.tabs = [{
      title: 'Postal Address',
      content: 'Dynamic content 1'
    },
    {
      title: 'Dynamic Title 2',
      content: 'Dynamic content 2',
      disabled: true
    }
  ];
}
angular
  .module('opsUI.tabs.controller', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('TabsCtrl1', Controller);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="app-bar-container">
  <div class="col-md-2" style="border-right: 1px solid #F2F2F2; padding-right: 15px;">
    <button data-ng-controller="TabsCtrl1" class="menu" data-ng-show="menu"><img src="/../images/hamburger.svg"></button>Menu
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="/../images/multiply.png" alt="" style="padding-left: 15px; height: 35px;width: 135px; margin-top:18px;" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help, but still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/ng/areq?p0=TabsCtrl1&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined